# Can you create an event using the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to be able to use the Facebook APIs to create events for facebook pages.  From this link it seems to not be allowed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event

Am I missing something? It seems like this was available in the past and I have no idea why it would not be available now.

Comment: According to the documentation it's not possible anymore

Comment: Yes, it was available in v1.0 but is not available in v2.0

Comment: Ugh, it seems odd as events are something you can advertise.  Not being able to create an event means there are less things to advertise on FB.

Answer (score 1):

Creating events via the API was allowed in v1.0, but has been removed in the newer Graph API v2.0. Facebook has removed several permission permissions from various end-points, including events, to prevent abuse.